# Can one make PHP ignore static method errors when using PEAR Mail extension?

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error, pear

I am using the PEAR Mail extension for PHP 5. I am having difficulties sending mail because it returns this error: `Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically`.

This is my code:

```
$from = "Stephen <stephen@gmail.com>";
     $to = "helper <helperjohn@gmail.com>";
     $subject = "Email Test!";
     $body = "email test body";

     $host = "smtp.nvrforget.com";
     $username = "username@nvrforget.com";
     $password = "*************";

     $headers = array ('From' => $from,
       'To' => $to,
       'Subject' => $subject);
     $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
       array ('host' => $host,
         'auth' => true,
         'username' => $username,
         'password' => $password));

     $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

     if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
       echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
      } else {
       echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
      }
```

I am not receiving the email.

I would use Swiftmailer if I could, but my webhost does not let me.

Comment: can't you just upload the swiftmailer files along with your other php files? the webhost shouldn't have to install anything for you. another popular one you could use is phpmailer

Comment: @bumperbox thanks! Just put Swiftmailer on and it works like a charm :).

Answer (score 5):

As PEAR still maintains PHP4 support, you can either...

1. Create a mail object to use, eg

   ```
   $mail = new Mail;
   $smtp = $mail->factory(...
   ```

   or
2. Disable `E_STRICT` errors

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
   ```

If you insist on using PEAR, the latter may be preferable due to internal static calls to other non-static methods.